# For each para ingresar datos en matriz

Tags: java

Se me solicita "Utilice una instrucción for mejorado para inicializar cada elemento del arreglo con la suma de sus índices"

Sin embargo, lo he intentado con el siguiente código:

```
int TAM = 3;
int[][] tabla = new int[TAM][TAM];
int j = 0;
      
for(int []x:tabla)
{        
    for(int y:x)
    {
        tabla[j][y] = j + y;
    }               
}
```

Sin embargo no funciona, leí en un foro en ingles que básicamente no es posible cambiar los datos de una matriz con un for mejorado, solo visualizarlos. Es verdad?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado correcto final que esperas de la pregunta que acabas de hacer?

Answer (score 1):

> No sé por qué te pidieron realizar ese ejercicio con ciclos `foreach`,
> pero aquí te dejo una solución, aunque debo aclarar que los parámetros
> (`int[]` x e `int y`) en los ciclos no son usados.

```
    int TAM = 3;
    int[][] tabla = new int[TAM][TAM];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int contadorVueltas = 0;

    for(int[] x : tabla) {
        for(int y : x) {
            tabla[i][j] = i + j;
            System.out.printf("%d ", tabla[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i = ++contadorVueltas;
        j = 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
        0 1 2 
        1 2 3 
        2 3 4
```